# Copy the content of text-area using radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to copy current address into permanent address using a radio button. I am using Onclick event but it's not working. Here is my code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"][name="perm_address"]').click(function() {
    $('#permanent_add').val() = ($('#current-address').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Address details</h3>
<input type="radio" id="html" name="perm_address" value="HTML" onclick="function()">
<label for="html">Permanent Address same as present address</label><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <label for="Present"><h4>Present Address</h4></label>
      <%= user_detail.text_area :contact_address, class: "form-control", :required => true,id:'current-address' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label for="permanent_address"><h4>Permanent Address</h4></label>
        <%= user_detail.text_area :permanent_address, class: "form-control", :required => true ,id:'permanent_add'%>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Should be `$('#permanent_add').val($('#current-address').val());`. `.val()` get the value, and `.val("something")` sets the value

Comment: Off topic: why would you use a *radio*?  There's no way to unset it without another radio, so if you do copy then edit the original, you can't copy again (as already "checked").  Use `<button type="button"`

Comment: Thanx @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple to just create a generic button that links two inputs together:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.copypasta').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const elements = this.form.elements,
          source = elements[this.dataset.source],
          target = elements[this.dataset.target];
    if (!source || !target) {
      throw 'source or target cannot be found in the form';
    }
    target.value = source.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button class="copypasta" data-source="foo" data-target="bar">Copy foo to bar</button>
  <div>
    <input name="foo" type="text" value="hello world" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="bar" type="text" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This works by simply using the form API provided by the browser that makes it easy find other inputs in the same form by name.

The configuration (the names) are supplied through data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to continue on the path you started down, I fixed the several errors in your code.

- You don't need an `onclick` handler in your html. I removed that.
- There were 2 missing `</div>` closing tags.
- Some `id` names were incorrect.
- `$('#permanent_add').val() = ($('#current-address').val());` is invalid jQuery. Corrected to `$('#permanent_address').val($('#current_address').val());`

As pointed out in the comments, the use of a radio button here is not practical. A checkbox or button would be better options.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"][name="perm_address"]').click(function() {
    $('#permanent_address').val($('#current_address').val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Address details</h3>
<input type="radio" id="html" name="perm_address" value="HTML" />
<label for="html">Permanent Address same as present address</label><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <label for="current_address"><h4>Present Address</h4></label>
      <input type="text" id="current_address" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label for="permanent_address"><h4>Permanent Address</h4></label>
        <input type="text" id="permanent_address" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @max. I removed that.